# Multiple back button clicks not being returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `history.pushState` to save state on a SPA but when I hit back button it only does it first time, then always to same page.

In the links below I click **About**, then **Web**, then **Portfolio**.

I'm now on **Portfolio**, when I click the back button it goes back to **Web**, when I click back button again it stays on **Web**, it does not go back to **About** - should it? Can it?

html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="loadPage('about'); return false;">About</a></li>                             
  <li><a href="#" onclick="loadPage('web'); return false;">Web</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="loadPage('portfolio'); return false;">Portfolio</a></li> 
</ul>
```

When a user clicks one of the links, content loads and the state is saved.

JS

```
function loadPage(page){

    // clear DIV and load new content
    var el = document.getElementById('main-block');
    el.innerHTML = '';
    $( "#main-block" ).load( page+'.html #main-block' );

    // change URL and save state
    history.pushState( {
      pageHistory: page 
    }, null, "/"+page );

  }

  // back button
  window.onpopstate = function (event) {  
    var content = "";
    if(event.state) {
      content = event.state.pageHistory;
    }
    loadPage(content);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click Back, you cannot add new state into history:

```
function loadPage(page, back){

    // clear DIV and load new content
    var el = document.getElementById('main-block');
    el.innerHTML = '';
    $( "#main-block" ).load( page+'.html #main-block' );

    // change URL and save state
    if (true !== back) {
        history.pushState( {
          pageHistory: page
        }, null, "/"+page );
    }

  }

  // back button
  window.onpopstate = function (event) {
    var content = "";
    if(event.state) {
      content = event.state.pageHistory;
    }
    loadPage(content, true);
  }
```

Comment: Awesome, just learning all this and that makes perfect sense, I thought there SHOULD be a way - thanks